# WAM in URDF for Gazebo

Tags: urdf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone!!

My name is Ivan, I'm new in this comunity,and I write because I need a robot for my project wam in a file URDF to gazebo. But the truth is not where to find one (and for that matter, I've been late on my project and I tried to create but favorable Last results)
Anyone know where I can find one??
thank everyone in advance
Greetings

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9865/wam-in-urdf-for-gazebo/) by [Ivan Rojas Jofre](https://answers.ros.org/users/398/ivan-rojas-jofre/) on ROS Answers with karma: 70 on 2011-05-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you are looking for an urdf for a wam arm, then take a look at the arm simulator project
http://thearmrobot.com/aboutSimulator.html

Then you can use
$ rosrun gazebo gazebo__model -h

To guide you through converting a urdf to gazebo XML format.

Or your can write a launch script to run gazebo with your urdf. Look in gazebo_worlds package for examples.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.ros.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 431 on 2011-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Benjamin Blumer](https://answers.ros.org/users/3673/benjamin-blumer/) on 2013-11-08**:
I don't have enough karma to edit this answer.  But I've recently made an SDF and some easy-to-use sample plugins for controlling a WAM. The SDF is made from the Institute De Robotica's URDF. Find it here: https://github.com/BenBlumer/Gazebo_WAM